# How to rewrite the SQL Server SUM(1) in LINQ C#?

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a SQL Server query and I rewrite this query in c# by using LINQ.

In the T-SQL query, there is a sum like that:

```
SELECT Date, Name, SUM(1) AS ItemCount, SUM(ProductCount) AS ProductCount 
FROM somewhere
GROUP BY Date, Name
```

I write the `SUM(ProductCount)` in C# like `x.Sum(i=>i.ProductCount)` and it is working.

But I have no idea how can I write the `SUM(1)` in C#.

Edit:
My LINQ

```
var list=_context.ProductList
.GroupBy(t=> new{ t.Date, t.Name})
.Select(i=> new ShipmentList(){ 
Date= i.Key.Created, 
Name=i.Key.Name, 
ItemCount= ?? , 
ProductCount=i.Sum(x=>x.ProductCount)}).ToList();
```

I search the ?? part in this code.

Comment: `SUM(1)` is the equivalent of `COUNT(*)`. Maybe that'll help you to find what you need to do in Linq.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I will try your solution. So do you have an idea about how can I  write the `Count(*)` in linq. There is no method like `x.Count().All`

Comment: Can you show your full `linq`

Comment: @PeterSmith I add the full `linq` in question.

Comment: ItemCount  = i.Count()

Comment: @MarcG and Charlieface both have what you seek; does that solve the problem?